# Are there any Videos/Screen casts on how to use exceptions in Delphi

Tags: delphi, video, exception

Hi are there any nice videos on how to use exceptions in Delphi.

Comment: Do you have specific questions or something you would like to see?  Just the basics, or more advanced stuff.

Comment: I am after the basics and more advanced stuff

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an [article on the basics](http://conferences.codegear.com/article/32156), a video on [exceptions in constructors & destructors](http://codegearguru.com/video/030/TSuicide.html), and [another video](http://cc.codegear.com/item/26436) on [delayed exception handling](http://www.davinciunltd.com/code/delayed-exceptions/).

Answer (score 7):

Jim McKeeth did one for CodeRage III called:
"Delayed Exception Handling
This is a more robust way of handling exceptions. Learn to prevent memory leaks and simplify code when dealing with multiple objects. This is an advanced session taking advantage of some of the latest Delphi 2009 features."

See:
Wednesday, December 3, 2008
7:00pm - 8:00pm
Room 1
http://conferences.codegear.com/coderage08/sessions

Although I've downloaded it I haven't had a chance to view it yet.

Comment: Hi Jim thanks for the excellent video - The two levels of Exception Handling in Delphi 2009 look very useful.

Answer (score 2):

There's also Jim's session for Coderage 2: [Exceptional Exceptions](http://video.codegear.com/CodeRageIIArchives/Day4/JimMcKeeth_ExceptionalExceptions.zip)
(ping Jim: I didn't see the link on your [web page](http://www.davinciunltd.com/code/exceptions/))

Answer (score 1):

I made one awhile ago: 
[Movie #30 - Exceptions in Constructors and Destructors](http://codegearguru.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=58&Itemid=27).